# Is there a way to select records from Oracle and lock them to avoid being read by another request?

Tags: java, oracle, locking

I have a java based webservice (REST API) that needs to read records from a table in Oracle DB. There is a possibility that 2 requests may be fired to that API at the same time thereby leading to same records being selected by both the requests for processing.

How to avoid this issue? Oracle allows only select and I dont know how we can efficiently lock records?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [SELECT ... FOR UPDATE](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/statements_10002.htm#i2066346) clause.

If both sessions select the same rows **and** provide this clause, one of them will be locked until the other session releases the lock.

Answer (score 0):

I'm really skeptical of this requirement. You say your REST API will read records in a table. There is therefore no need to lock the rows in the table. Two sessions can read values from the same table just fine. Oracle guarantees read consistency for a statement, so you know each statement reflects the table as of a single instant in time.

If you need to execute *multiple* select statements against a table and you're afraid it will have been modified in between the two statements, you can do `ALTER SESSION SET TRANSACTION READ ONLY` to give you **transaction level read consistency**. You don't need to lock anything.

> All subsequent queries in that transaction see only changes that were
>   committed before the transaction began. Read-only transactions are
>   useful for reports that run multiple queries against one or more
>   tables while other users update these same tables.

https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/statements_10005.htm#SQLRF01705